# SPDY and Tomcat 8

Tags: spdy, tomcat8

Tomcat 8 provides *experimental* support for SPDY protocol, according to these sources: Tomcat's [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications), [API docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/spdy/package-summary.html), [version 8.0.0 changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html).
I understand it's still work in progress but I'd like to try it out. Unfortunately there's very little documentation on the subject.
So has anyone used SPDY with Tomcat? Can you explain how to enable it or share needed configuration?

Comment: [Changelog 8.0.22](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.0.22_%28markt%29) "Remove the experimental support for SPDY. ..."

Comment: Related: [HTTP/2 support in Tomcat 8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29365294/531762)

Answer (score 2):

I was very successful in configuring NGINX with SPDY, and it's super fast.  You could always use NGINX and proxy requests to Tomcat.  Also, Jetty seems to have some great support for SPDY and SPDY Push features if you need native Servlet containers.  As of today, [nginx does not support SPDY push](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html) "Current implementation of SPDY protocol does not support “server push”.".

http://www.chromium.org/spdy

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/SPDY